# how much time will this sleep time take with a pipe

Tags: pipe

I'm trying to understand pipes better.
How much time will the following process take if typed into command line?
sleep 30 | sleep 40

I think 40 seconds if they run at the same time?

Comment: What keeps you from trying? E.g. `date; sleep 30 | sleep 40; date`. Or even with a stopwatch. Or using `sleep 1 | sleep 40` and your ability to tell 1 second from 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ time $(sleep 30 | sleep 40)

real    0m40.004s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.003s
```

yes. I believe the pipe starts immediately after the command starts and do output and input operation.So it would take the longest possible time to complete the command.

Also , *you cannot predict the time of pipe operation*.It totally depends on system CPU's i/o capability at that particular point of time.

```
$ cat file
test

$ time grep test file
test

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.003s

$ time grep test file | grep test
test

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.002s
```

Answer (score 1):

The broken out pieces of a pipeline happen concurrently, they are executing independently of one another (unless there is some IO happening which in your case there isn't).

Your process will only ever take as long as the longest `sleep` you're issuing. In your case, 40 seconds.

Stalin Vignesh Kumar has shown you examples and elaborated.