# How to pipeline sleep? sleep pipeline doesn't work

Tags: pipe, time, sleep, delay

I wanted to simulate execution time of certain scripts for which I found `sleep NUMBER` does exactly what I want.

In my scenario I needed something like

```
sleep 5 | command | sleep 5 ...
```

But it behaved strangely so I've tested `sleep`s alone, and I was surprised that

This takes 10 seconds `sleep 10 | sleep 5`

and **this also takes 10 seconds** `sleep 5 | sleep 10`

I even tried `sleep 1 | sleep` in case sleep was listening to standard input stdin

Only thing I got working is when I was looking on how to force stdout as argument (with `xargs`)

```
sleep 3; echo 3 | xargs sleep; echo "finished"
```

But since I need to time the whole execution I had to do

```
time -p (sleep 3; echo 3) | (xargs sleep; echo "finished")
```

Hoe to pipe sleeps? If there is a better way, I'd still ike to know why `sleep 1 | sleep 1` isn't working in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what order do piped commands run?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run)

Comment: And also pretty much the same thing in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594070/how-much-time-will-this-sleep-time-take-with-a-pipe

Comment: @muru it only explains why isn't it working or it works the way it does, but does not answer how to properly pipe sleeps so they'd run in serial mode,

Comment: There is no serial mode in pipes. They run in parallel. That is the point. If you want them to run serially, run them serially and use temp files or something for passing around output.

Comment: Also, it's unclear why you do something like `(sleep 3; echo 3 | (xargs sleep; echo finished)` - what is the `sleep 3` doing in the left side, and why `echo | xargs`? If you want to delay the second `echo`, `| (sleep 3; echo finished)` is enough.

Comment: @muru that was an example, first wait 3 seconds before doing command 1, then send 3 with echo to next sleep which will sleep for those 3 seconds too and then command 2

Comment: I guess my issue was with time `sleep 3; sleep 3` in itself works thanks, but `time sleep 3; sleep 3` prints time only of the first command, so I guess solution to that according to those answers would be `time (sleep 3; sleep 3)` ?

Comment: I'm still not clear as to why you want those many sleeps. Say you have a pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2 | ... | cmdn`, and you're faking `cmd5`, then only `cmd5` needs to be `(sleep; echo)`. Why do the rest need `sleep`? And if there are multiple faked commands, and they are *adjacent*, only the last needs a `sleep`.

Comment: @muru there are multiple commands but only some of them are simulated and some of them should wait before starting another etc. it's mainly for some visual confirmations

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "visual confirmations" but maybe you will find [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612027/432690) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to separate with `;` instead of `|`

```
sleep 10; echo hi; sleep 5
```

This will wait 10 seconds, echo hi, wait 5 seconds, then exit.

I think many of us are confused why you want to pipe the output of sleep (which doesn’t really have meaningful output) at all.  To tell the truth, the idea of piping sleep, while possible, had never occurred to me.

`;` is the syntax for running commands serially.